# PL/SQL define and initialize multi field array or table from text

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I've been searching for a way to do this and I just can't seem to find it.  I have a list of 3 pieces of data tag, time, and type.  there are multiple records (like 280+) in a text (csv) file.

In PL/SQL developer I have a command file, in which i want to declare an array, and fill it from the values in the text file, but since I can't put the file on the server, I can't use the file as an external data source.  I need to copy/paste the values into the PL\SQL block file that I'm working with.  Something like the following

```
declare
  type v_data is RECORD (tag number, time varchar2(12), type varchar2(15)) ;

  type v_data_table is table of v_data index by binary_integer;
  v_list v_data_table := v_data_table(v_data(1,'6:00 am','ONE'), v_data(240,'11:00 am', 'TWO'));
```

But i am getting an error that function v_data does not exist in the current scope when declaring the v_list variable.  I've even tried moving the v_list initialize statement into the PL/SQL block, after the begin, like so;

```
 declare
   type v_data is RECORD (tag number, time varchar2(12), type varchar2(15)) ;

   type v_data_table is table of v_data index by binary_integer;
   v_list v_data_table ;
 begin
   v_list := v_data_table(v_data(1,'6:00 am','ONE'), v_data(240,'11:00 am', 'TWO'));
```

same error... any help is appreciated!

Comment: "since I can't put the file on the server, I can't use the file as an external data source"...that's false...assuming Oracle DBA account user is given permission... external directories can be network locations on other machines...I use this often

Comment: You have two issues. The first is that you are trying to construct a `RECORD` type as though it were an `OBJECT` type. If your type were an object, then you get a default constructor that does exactly what you are attempting. Second, you are using a table type indexed by binary_integer. Any table type with an index type declared cannot be built in bulk like this. You need to remove that piece of the declaration.

Comment: Also `binary_integer` is the old name for `pls_integer`.

Comment: @HepC - thanks, can you expound a bit?  Maybe move your explanation into an answer instead of a comment.  Once I test this, I'll give you the solution point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Thanks to HepC and a little Google-fu, I got a script that worked.

```
set serveroutput on size 1000000
create type v_data AS OBJECT (tag number, time varchar2(12), type varchar2(15)) ;
/
declare
type v_data_table is table of v_data index by binary_integer;
v_list v_data_table := v_data_table(v_data(1,'6:00 am','ONE'), v_data(240,'11:00 am', 'TWO'));
begin
  for i in v_list.first..v_list.Last
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TAG: ' || to_char(v_list(i).tag));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TAG: ' || v_list(i).time);   
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TAG: ' || v_list(i).type);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
drop type v_data;
/
set serveroutput off;
/
```

I was worried about creating the type on the server, since it's a production server, and this is a one-off script, I didn't want a stray type taking up precious resources.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE

   type v_data is RECORD 
   ( tag number
   , time varchar2(12)
   , type varchar2(15));

   type v_data_table is table of v_data index by binary_integer;

   v_list v_data_table ;

   PROCEDURE add_new_data(new_tag number
                        , new_time varchar2
                        , new_type varchar2)
      IS
      BEGIN

         v_list(v_list.COUNT + 1).tag := new_tag;
         v_list(v_list.COUNT).time    := new_time;
         v_list(v_list.COUNT).type    := new_type;

      END add_new_data;

BEGIN

   add_new_data(1, '6:00 am', 'ONE');
   add_new_data(240, '11:00 am', 'TWO');

END;
/
```

Comment: I didn't try this, so I'm not sure if it works.  but in your procedure you're adding the tag to count + 1 and the time and type to count.  Is Count a dynamic property like that, or would you need to EXTEND the v_list first before adding to it. I tried declaring v_data as a record, and that worked, similar to this solution, you can see it in my solution on this post.  Thanks for your attempt!!

Comment: no need to extend. count simply gives the number of element in the array so far. if the pl table has 10 rows, count + 1 returns 11, so count + 1 is saying add row at index 11. the 2 next lines count returns 11, so you're adding the values to the row at index 11.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE

   type v_data is RECORD 
   ( tag number
   , time varchar2(12)
   , type varchar2(15));

   type v_data_table is table of v_data index by binary_integer;

   v_list v_data_table ;

BEGIN

   v_list(v_list.COUNT + 1).tag := 1;
   v_list(v_list.COUNT).time    := '6:00 am';
   v_list(v_list.COUNT).type    := 'ONE';

   v_list(v_list.COUNT + 1).tag := 240;
   v_list(v_list.COUNT).time    := '11:00 am';
   v_list(v_list.COUNT).type    := 'TWO';

END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks Ray, but this is what I'm trying to avoid, all the timestaking declarations of v_list iterations, I have 280+ and I've already used NotePad++ to encase them in brackets and single quotes.  I want to bulk declare the v_list variable in one statement then iterate through it.  Close